# Given a discrete distribution, how do I round a number to the closest value in that distribution?

Tags: python, scipy

What I ultimately want to do is round the expected value of a discrete random variable distribution to a valid number in the distribution. For example if I am drawing evenly from the numbers [1, 5, 6], the expected value is 4 but I want to return the closest number to that (ie, 5).

```
from scipy.stats import *
xk = (1, 5, 6)
pk = np.ones(len(xk))/len(xk)
custom = rv_discrete(name='custom', values=(xk, pk))
print(custom.expect())   
# 4.0

def round_discrete(discrete_rv_dist, val):
    # do something here
    return answer

print(round_discrete(custom, custom.expect()))
# 5.0
```

I don't know apriori what distribution will be used (ie might not be integers, might be an unbounded distribution), so I'm really struggling to think of an algorithm that is sufficiently generic. Edit: I just learned that rv_discrete doesn't work on non-integer xk values.

As to *why* I want to do this, I'm putting together a monte-carlo simulation, and want a "nominal" value for each distribution. I think that the EV is the most physically appropriate rather than the mode or median. I might have values in the downstream simulation that have to be one of several discrete choices, so passing a value that is not within that set is not acceptable.

If there's already a nice way to do this in Python that would be great, otherwise I can interpret math into code.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Consider a 6-sided die.  The expected value is 3.5, it's not 3 and it's not 4.  You're no more likely to get a 3 or 4 than to get any other value.  I find that usually when people want to round an expected value to a nearby integer, it's because they have a misconception about expected values -- it should *not* be considered representative of what outcome you're going to get.

Comment: I'm putting together a monte-carlo simulation, and want a "nominal" value for each distribution. I think that the EV is the most physically appropriate rather than the mode, mean, or median (plus the latter two also run into the same issue of rounding). I might have values in the downstream simulation that have to be one of several discrete choices, so passing a value that is not within that set is not acceptable.

Comment: Using a value which isn't the mean can bias results.

Comment: My mistake, the mean and expected value are equivalent. I miswrote the sentence above that implies otherwise.

Comment: A note of dissent here. It is not perverse or paradoxical to have non-integer means for variables that can only be integers. The point is made in elementary courses that family size mean can be expected to have a mean with fractional part. You give a why, but I don'f find it clear.

Comment: I'm generating randomized inputs for simulations which reflect a physical reality where inputs are discrete. Think of a lever that might be in different positions. I would like to make a "nominal" run with near-mean inputs so the user has an idea of what an "average" result might be, but you can't lock a lever in a halfway position. So I'd like to go to the closest valid position.

Comment: I'll also add that there isn't a built in way (or solid add-on way that I've seen) to get the mode of an arbitrary discrete distribution, so that isn't an option for this use case either.

Comment: If that's your use case, you should be running an ensemble of experiments with the input randomized according to the distribution.  Trying to replace a distribution with its mean will yield incorrect expected outcomes unless the model is itself a linear transformation.  Going back to my six-sided die example, you'd do far better to have the input be any of the values 1 through 6 selected at random than by always entering a 3 or 4.  Replacing distributional behavior with a constant stand-in is generally a recipe for disaster, because you don't get to see how the variance propagates.

Comment: Yes, the ensemble of experiments is *exactly* the full monte-carlo setup I'm putting together here, and I will be drawing from the distributions for the suite of my other cases. I *still* want a "nominal" run that can be looked at on its own for the user to build intuition. Some things (for example, the timing of linked discrete events within the simulation) would get smeared out when examining averaged results from the full ensemble, and it would be difficult for the user to understand an example sequence of events. I know what I need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, and tested it working. If I plug my value X into the cdf, then I can plug that probability P = cdf(X) into the ppf. The values at ppf(P +- epsilon) will give me the closest values in the set to X.

Or more geometrically, for a discrete pmf, the point (X,P) will lie on a horizontal portion of the corresponding cdf. When you invert the cdf, (P,X) is now on a vertical section of the ppf. Taking P +- eps will give you the 2 nearest flat portions of the ppf connected to that vertical jump, which correspond to the valid values X1, X2. You can then do a simple difference to figure out which is closer to your target value.

```
import numpy as np
eps = np.finfo(float).eps

ev = custom.expect()
p = custom.cdf(ev)
ev_candidates = custom.ppf([p - eps, p, p + eps])
ev_candidates_distance = abs(ev_candidates - ev)
ev_closest = ev_candidates[np.argmin(ev_candidates_distance)]
print(ev_closest)
# 5.0
```

Terms:
pmf - probability mass function
cdf - cumulative distribution function (cumulative sum of the pdf)
ppf - percentage point function (inverse of the cdf)
eps - epsilon (smallest possible increment)

Comment: Closest in what sense?

Comment: Absolute difference. I've updated my answer with working code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is R code that I think will do what you want, using Poisson data to illustrate:

```
set.seed(322)
x = rpois(100, 7)      # 100 obs from POIS(7)
a = mean(x); a
[1] 7.16               # so 7 is the value we want
d = min(abs(x-a)); d   # min distance btw a and actual Pois val
[1] 0.16
u = unique(x); u       # unique Pois values observed
[1]  7  5  4 10  2  9  8  6 11  3 13 14 12 15
v = u[abs(u-a)==d]; v  # unique val closest to a
[1] 7
```

Hope you can translate it to Python.

Another run:

```
set.seed(323)
x = rpois(100, 20)
a = mean(x); a
[1] 20.32
d = min(abs(x-a)); d
[1] 0.32
u = unique(x)
v = u[abs(u-a)==d]; v
[1] 20

x
 [1] 17 16 20 23 23 20 19 23 21 19 21 20 22 25 13 15 19 19 14 27 19 30 17 19 23
[26] 16 23 26 33 16 11 23 14 21 24 12 18 20 20 19 26 12 22 24 20 22 17 23 11 19
[51] 19 26 17 17 11 17 23 21 26 13 18 28 22 14 17 25 28 24 16 15 25 26 22 15 23
[76] 27 19 21 17 23 21 24 23 22 23 18 25 14 24 25 19 19 21 22 16 28 18 11 25 23
u
 [1] 17 16 20 23 19 21 22 25 13 15 14 27 30 26 33 11 24 12 18 28
```

Comment: I believe this would only work if you do enough draws to get lucky and land on the correct answer. This would likely not work for distributions with large support, especially if the mode and mean are not close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Would the function ceil from the math library help? For example:

```
from math import ceil
print(float(ceil(3.333333333333333)))
```

Comment: No, perhaps my example is confusing that way. I changed the numbers to try and make the problem clearer.